# How do I compare the std::map's body members?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, comparison, compare

I am keeping a structure B based on a key A in a stl::map.  I am writing code that based on any updates to any member of the body of the above map from the old values, I will print an alert.

I have no idea hoew to do that. I have researched the internet.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: To clarify the question, what you want to obtain is code that will trigger some sort of alert (what type?) if an object that resides inside a map changes? What circumstances should trigger that alert? What should the alert be like?

Comment: One correction to the question title is stl::map. Another correction to the question is that if any member of the structure B which is the map body changes, how do I detect that? is there a call already available for  that or should I check member by member with an if  (b.x == b.second.x)  ?  Thanks

Comment: @DavidRodriguez, No I just want to know how do I detect a change, I will just do a printf after I detect a change. So, my issue is: is there a function call to detect (true or false kind of thing) a chnage in any of the map's body members from last time?? Does that make sense now?

Comment: I have **voted to close** as the question seems to be unrelated to the problem at hand. After reading user comments on Tony's answer, it seems that the question should be something in the lines of "Can I compare two structs without performing all member wise comparisons?" or something related. The current question focuses on `std::map` which is unrelated to the problem, and is thus confusing. The actual question would be missing information on what the actual struct is (is it a POD? what types does it contain?)

Answer (score 3):

If the types used as key and values have `operator==` defined, the simplest expensive solution is keeping a backup of the map, and then comparing both maps:

```
std::map<key,value> the_map;
std::map<key,value> test_copy; // hidden from the rest of the code
                               // copied from the_map on particular instants
bool map_has_changed() {
   return the_map != test_copy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct foo 
{
   // foo members
};

bool isEqual(const std::map<int,foo>& map1, const std::map<int,foo>& map2)
{
   std::map<int,foo>::const_iterator itr1, itr2;
   for (itr1 = map1.begin(), itr2 = map2.begin(); itr1 != map1.end(), itr2 != map2.end(); itr1++, itr2++)
   {
      if (itr1->first != itr2->first) return false;
      if (!isEqual(itr1->second, itr2->second)) return false;
   }
   return true;
}

bool isEqual(const foo& f1, const foo& f2)
{
   // some implementation that checks if f1 and f2 are equal
}
```

The downside of this implementation is that it assumes that the members of each map are in the same order (which means they are inserted into in the same order). If they could be a different order, then you will need to do something like this for the std::map isEqual:

```
bool isEqual(const std::map<int,foo>& map1, const std::map<int,foo>& map2)
{
   std::map<int,foo>::const_iterator itr, temp;
   for (itr = map1.begin(); itr != map1.end(); itr++)
   {
      temp = map2.find(itr->first);
      if (!temp) return false;
      if (!isEqual(itr->second, temp->second)) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

The first implementation will be faster, but again, it assumes that the map is in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the map and do a comparison:

```
std::map<int, std::string> my_map;
int someint = 2;
std::string mystr = "tony";
std::map<int, std::string>::iterator it;

for (it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end() it++)
{
    if (it->first == someint) 
      { 
          //do something 
      }

    if (it->second == mystr) 
       { 
         // do something else 
       }
}
```

Make sure if your map contains custom objects that comparison operators are properly implemented.

Comment: my map is std::map<int, someStructwithManyMembers> my_map;

Comment: @user: if you don't mention that in your question, then I wouldn't know, principle is still the same however

Comment: I think I am not doing a good job at explaining my question :  I think my question is if I have stl::map<int, somestructure> mymap1 and the stl::map <int, somestructure> mymap2 then is there a wholesale way (for lakc of a better word) to compare mymap1.somestructure with mymap2.somestructure  without having to compare member by memeber.  Thank you for your help,  in advance.

Comment: @user553514: So basically you are asking a question that is completely unrelated to a map but titling the question "how to compare std::map's body members"? Half of the way to an answer is providing the actual question that you are interested in.